# Attempting to sort a list that is generated from a unique point extraction of an array

Tags: excel

The issue is sorting an array that is generated automatically from an data source using a formula that extracts unique data points. (Data points are date/time)

The data is being extracted with this fomula.

```
=INDEX(Table_ExternalData_1[SampleDateTime],MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($G$2:G2,Table_ExternalData_1[SampleDateTime]),0,0),0))
```

Once extracted, the data is not sorted right away. The current data is extracted from a database via an SQL string that pulls in data corresponding to the data and time that the data point was created.

Because of this, the extracted points are not in the correct order. I am attempting to sort the extracted data points from earliest to latest to continue with the data sorting, but need the date/times to be sorted in a separate row.

I have attempted to use a pivot table, but it isn't exactly what I need and ends up being a messier end product than I need.

All assistance is appreciated.
Example is below.

1

2

3

5

1

2

3

4

6

5

3

I need this.

1

2

3

4

5

6

I did end up finding a solution that I will be able to modify. Using a single row of a pivot table, I took just the date/time column and had the PivotTable function sort the data to be utilized as necessary.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps a small, mocked-up example of 10 rows or so, including expected results, would help.

Comment: Of course. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the range in the example you give:

1) Consists of entries of a numeric datatype only

2) Does not contain any blanks

means that the solution is relatively simple.

Assuming that data is in `A1:A11`, first use a single cell somewhere within the worksheet to count the number of expected returns. For example, using `B1` for this purpose, enter this formula in that cell:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:A11,A1:A11),1))`

Your main formula is then:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>B$1,"",SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(A$1:A$11,A$1:A$11),A$1:A$11),ROWS($1:1)))`

the latter being copied down until you start to get blanks for the results.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your help!